# Laptop stopped recognizing USB hard drive

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-storage

My Packard Bell EasyNote TX86 laptop stopped recognizing my 1 TB Toshiba Store Art hard drive. It worked fine until now, and it still works on other computers. Other USB devices (including storage) work, and I've tried plugging it in every port, to no avail. When I plug it in it spins up, but Windows doesn't react at all (it's not in disk management), Linux doesn't write anything in dmesg and I can't see it in BIOS setup. I didn't use it at all today, apart from plugging it into a freshly-installed Windows 7 machine once (where it worked).

What can I do? Which device is to blame here?

EDIT: One more thing. I unplugged the drive while the laptop was hibernated. Google says this might be the problem and it might have something to do with resetting the USB Host Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate may cause some problems - but that wouldn't explain it not working in Linux or after a reset.

You say other devices have worked - all I can think of / suggest is, have you tried a different USB socket in case that it is the socket that is damaged. Again, if it was related to hibernate, a restart should solve it and a restart to Linux should not be affected at all.

Comment: I tried all of them. What's really frustrating is that I don't know if the hard drive or the laptop is to blame.

Comment: @Vahokif - I think it is the laptop to blame, but the fact that it doesn't work in Linux either, I am clueless. Sorry I can't help further.

Answer (score 1):

Try to go in Computer management by right click on My Compute Icon and go to Device Manager>Usb Serial Port and uninstall all USB Root HUB. And reboot your computer and then connect your HDD.

[image]

As  in my PC all USB Root Hub are showing normally but if any one is not working then windows show a Yellow Mark on it then uninstall it and when you will reboot windows will find the new hardware and install automatically for your system. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! My USB 3 hub was not working, but **right-click-uninstall** and then **right-click-scan PC for hardware changes** in device manager fixed it.